# Templates C#/MVC 4/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Create Shared UI Templates with C# + MVC 4 + Razor Engine.

### The problem

I do not know how to do.

### Details

I have the follow template:

```
<li>
    <div class="introduction">
        <h3>{productName}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="presentation">
        <img src="{productImage}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <p>Starting by</p>
        <h3>{minProductPrice}</h3>
        <p class="product-unity">/a <span class="product-measure" 
         data-measure-shortcut="{productMeasureShortname">{productMeasureName}
        </span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="button green add" title="Add to comparsion list">+</button>
        <div class="tooltip-quantity">
            <p class="float-left">Quantity:</p>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input class="quantity float-left" name="product_quantity"
                maxlength="2" type="text" />
                <span class="float-left">/{productMeasureName}(s)</span>
                <button disabled class="button orange filled float-right">
                   Add
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <button class="button light-blue filled compare float-right" title="This product is available in 6 stores">Compare</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

and when I want to call it, I would to do something like this:

`@Html.RenderMyTemplate("Product Name", "Product Image", "Min Product Price"...)`

Logically, the parameters will replace the placeholders on the template.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("MyView", Model)
```

Basicaly it renders given file (`MyView`) using model (`Model`) as regular razor powered template.

In your case (I used `string[]` as `Model`, but you can use whatever you want e.g. `IDictionary<string, string>`):

```
@Html.Partial("MyView", new[] { "Product Name", "Product Image", "Min Product Price" })
```

In view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<string[]>
<li>@Model[0]</li>
```

**UPDATE (with dictionary)**

```
@Html.Partial("MyView", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "name", "Product1"}, { "price", 100 } })
```

then

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Dictionary<string, object>>
<li>@Model["name"]</li>
```

Comment: Can I name this index? I mean, there is a way to use `@Model['productName']`? Thanks!

Comment: You can, but you have to use `Dictionary` instead of `string[]`, let me edit my answer